# pass children to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how I can pass children what I was write in `React.render` to component? I try to rewrite this code(https://pastebin.com/Pwtnd7Yh) using `Component` how I can pass children to the component, in example code author write `...rest` what is it, and how I can pass data to my component?

```
    <script type="text/babel">
      const root = document.getElementById("root");

      class Block extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {size: props.size, style: props.style};
        }
        render(){
          const sizeClassName = this.state.size ? `box--${this.state.size}` : '';
          return(
            <div className={`box ${sizeClassName}`} style={{paddingLeft: 20, ...this.state.style}}  />
          )
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
        <Block size='small' style={{backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}}>small box</Block>
        <Block size='medium' style={{backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>medium box</Block>
        </div>,
        root
      )
    </script>
```

Comment: Not clear at all. Do you want to pass props ? Another Component as a child ?

Comment: ...rest are all the other props (rest is an object). I am not understanding your answer 100%. Do you want to pass children to "Block"?

Comment: Now I have two box, but without an inscription in it. I want to have 'small box' inscription in first box, and 'medium box' in another

Comment: @lipp yes, I want to pass children to Block.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem just add  `{...this.props} as a attribute.

```
  render(){
      const sizeClassName = this.state.size ? `box--${this.state.size}` : '';
      return(
        <div className={`box ${sizeClassName}`} style={{paddingLeft: 20, ...this.state.style}} {...this.props} />
      )
    }
```